# Where to format number strings? Server or browser?

Tags: database, efficiency, data-types, formatting

I am storing numbers in my database without formatting (e.g., 1434587). But I need a formatted string in the UX (e.g., $1,434,587).

Is it better to store the raw number AND the formatted value in the database? And simply retrieve it to show to the user? Or is it more efficient to only store the unformatted raw number only in the database, fetch that, then format it in the browser to show to the user?

Comment: I suggest to take a look to this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/331653/222996). Instead of number, questions turns around dates. But the answers are valid for your case too.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting should be done as late as possible.

Inside your application, you should represent data in a format that makes it easy to work with. E.g. you would probably represent numbers with a numeric type, not with strings. Currency values will often need a custom type in order to track different currencies (e.g. USD and EUR), and to store fractional values losslessly (floating point numbers are completely unsuitable for currencies).

Your application has various interfaces to the external world. These interfaces might connect the application to other software systems, or to (human) users. Each interface will have its individual requirements how data should be formatted. Therefore, the conversion should happen at the boundaries of your system, within the interface: convert to the internal format when data enters the system, and convert it back just before the data leaves the system.

For user interfaces, *localization* becomes important. Different users have different expectations how currencies or dates are formatted, or how text is sorted. In my locale, I would expect the value “1234567.89 USD” to be formatted as “1 234 567,89 $”. Different locales would expect “$12,34,567.89” or “$ 1'234'567,89”. It is not possible to handle all that variety throughout your application, and there is no common format understood by all locales. As a result, you have a choice of either ignoring locales, or performing any localization after your processing – usually inside the user interface code.